# Morris Graph, round y-axis numbers

Tags: javascript

I made a Morris.js graph: http://thuis.xitro.nl/

I do not want to set a value in ymin, I have this on "auto".
I now have very long numbers because of that, example: 55.29999999999999
I want that to show just 55.

It would be even better if my graph just showed: 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70.

How can I achieve this? I know some HTML/PHP/MySQL but I'm pretty new to JavaScript.

EDIT: Fixed it myself by using: yLabelFormat: function(y) {return y = Math.round(y);},

Any idea how I can get my chart like this: 20,30,40,50,60,70?

```
Morris.Line({
    // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
    element: 'morris-line-chart-dcr',
    // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
    // the chart.
    data: [<?php echo $chart_data_dcr; ?>],
    // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-visitss.
    xkey: 'time',
    // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-visitss.
    ykeys: ['eff', 'avg', 'rep'],
    // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
    // chart.
    labels: ['Decred Effective','Decred Average','Decred Reported'],
    lineColors: ['#337ab7','#ffa500','#5cb85c'],
    pointFillColors: ['#337ab7','#ffa500','#5cb85c'],
    pointStrokeColors: ['#337ab7','#ffa500','#5cb85c'],
    pointSize: 3,
    hideHover: true,
    ymax: "auto",
    ymin: "auto",
    // Disables line smoothing
    smooth: false,
    resize: true
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code inside Morris.line Graph

`yLabelFormat: function(y) {
  return y = Math.round(y);
}`

this will format the Y axis labels.

Comment: I found this code here and tried it before. But when I use it, all my labels will dissapear.

Comment: try changing the `ymin:0`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to keep ymin on auto, because otherwise the graph will get too big. Any ideas how to just format this correctly?

Answer (score 4):

yLabelFormat: function(y) {return y = Math.round(y);},

Fixed it for me.

Now I only would like to know how I can make them look like: 20,30,40,50,60,70.